# Front Mic and Audio Jack Wired Incorrectly

Tags: sound

I'm running into an unfortunate problem with a new PC case. The front mic and speaker jack appear to have been wired the wrong way around by the manufacturer. When I put my speakers into the mic jack I hear sound, but not when I plug my speaker into the audio port.

I'm just wondering if there is a way in software that I configure the ports to be the correct way around?

Comment: Why my post got voted down for?

Comment: Why does it need reversing? if you already hear the sound? Also the "lol" and bad language often causes downvotes. Proper english please.

Comment: Ok I didn't realise everyone was very picky about wording. I will stick to the facts in my questions from now on, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For intel hardware there is a tool that is part of the alsa-tools-gui package called hdajackretask. There is not a manpage but it offers. In your question you did not state what kind of onboard sound you have. This package cliaims to have the support itself. Once you install the package there is some documentation availabe by a button but there is not manpage so I can't like from manpages.ubuntu.com but I put the documentation to see if it meets your needs in a pastebin that won't expire here https://gist.github.com/be35a1e5824e16ee87c8

I don't know of anything for non intel hda soundcards however.